# Deploy QT5 app to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, qt-creator, qt5, glib

I made a QT Application under Ubuntu 14.04 32bit using QtCreator and QT 5.2.1. I used the binary distribution of QT framework. I followed all the tutorial about deploying QT application and on fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04 everything seems ok. The problems come with Ubuntu 12.04. When i try to run my app i get those Glib errors.

> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()
>
> (process:11884): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed
>
> (process:11884): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed
>
> (process:11884): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.32.4/./gobject/gtype.c:2722: You forgot to call g_type_init()

Can anyone help me to fix these?
Thanks

**Edit1:**
The app run with sudo, without the errors, but it doesn't display the icon (libappindicator1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages are telling you what the problem is:

```
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL... You forgot to call g_type_init()
```

In versions of [the GLib library](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) prior to 2.36, applications were required to call a [`g_type_init`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-init) function to initialize the library's [GObject type system](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/) and apparently your program is not doing this. (Note it could be a library your program builds against that uses GLib, not your actual code.) Presumably Ubuntu 12 ships with an older version of GLib than does Ubuntu 14 and that accounts for the difference in behaviour between them.

Try adding this code to your program right at the start of its `main` function:

```
if (glib_check_version (2, 36, 0) != NULL)
  g_type_init ();
```

You may also need to add this include at the top of the file, if it isn't already present:

```
#include <glib-object.h>
```

Note if you're building against a recent version of GLib, having `g_type_init` present in your code may trigger a warning from the compiler. If that's a problem, you can add

```
#define GLIB_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
```

at the *very top* of your code (before the GLib header is included) to prevent this.

Comment: Wow it worked! I noticed that the app starts correctly with sudo but without sudo it require g_type_init to run on ubuntu 12.04 vanilla. The problem is that i can't use GLIB_MAJOR_VERSION macro because i develop on ubuntu 14.04 with a glib 2.40.

Comment: I've changed my answer to suggest using a run-time version check instead of a compile-time one. That makes more sense, since (as I understand) you are _building_ on Ubuntu 14 but _deploying_ on Ubuntu 12. Please try this and let me know if this is a better solution.